# Id is null despite there being value

Tags: json, flutter

I have a Data class that store a List and I want to get the ImageListObj in that list but it said that it is null [image: The id is null]even thought there are value inside.(I use Flutter riverpod).

[image: There is value here]

Comment: Please copy paste your model codes here

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to fix this:

```
id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
```

As, you are trying to assign a null value to int, you are getting that error. To handle these types of error, set Null value to the variable if you are getting null from API RESPONSE.